# How to combine style into a theme?

Tags: java, android, xml, styles, themes

I have created a style:

```
 <style name="Button_Display">
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">88dip</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

I want that all the **Button's** in my application will look like declared above.
My question is how can i combine the *Button_Display* style inside a theme so all the Buttons in my app will have this look and feel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes

In `styles.xml` create your own button style. Choose whatever parent style matches your need the best. Then overwrite all the necessary parameters.

```
<style name="myButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">88dip</item>
     ...
</style>
```

Then set this as default button style in your theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat....">
      <item name="buttonStyle">@style/myButtonStyle</item>
       ...
</style>
```

Now all Buttons will have the parameters you specified in your style.

Comment: thanks i am after reading it and didn't understand nothing so i have asked here. Also i didn't find a situation exactly as i described

Comment: i edited it, being more detailed, hope this helps

Comment: thanks but `buttonStyle` isn't a reserved word, so how  the android will  automatically know that he needs to associate it Precisely with a `Button` and not with a `TextView` for example?

Comment: See the bottom of the page that i linked. It says to apply a style to all buttons just set the buttonStyle in your theme. This will not change TextViews.